# Access filed value within a java list object

Tags: java, field, listobject

Hey I have executed a stored procedure from java and it return a List and I can access each row in the
    list by list.get(int index);
but how to get each field?  I get error if I try
    list.get(int index).client

client cannot be resolved or is not a field.

{id=44, client=xyz, monday=, tuesday=263,4969,44,0,2,4,0%moredatahere, wednesday=, thursday=, friday=, saturday=, sunday=},
{id=45, client=xyz1, monday=, tuesday=, wednesday=263,4969,44,0,2,4,0%moredatahere, thursday=, friday=, saturday=, sunday=},

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a reference to just a `List` and not a `List<Foo>`. In this case, the Java compiler only understands that `List.get(int)` returns an object; it does not know the type.

Thus, you must explicitly cast the result of `List.get(int)` to the appropriate type. You did not mention what type you expect `get(int)` to return, so I'll call the type `Foo`. You want

```
Foo myFoo = (Foo) someList.get(someIndex);
```

Now you can access `client` as `myFoo.getClient`.